# Java versioning

Tags: java

From the installation manual of Oracle's JDEdwards EnterpriseOne

*JDK 1.5 is required. JDK 1.6 and higher have not been validated with
EnterpriseOne as of November, 2008*

As the sentence says, I need to get JDK 1.5. But the [download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html) says `Java SE 5` after `Java SE 1.4`. I imposed to think `Java SE 5` is `JDK 1.5`. Am I right ?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Oracle JDEdwards EnterpriseOne?

Comment: There used to be a 2 in there, too: "Java 2 Standard Edition 1.5" Sun Marketing for the win. I am surprised Oracle did not (yet?) change it to Java 6.0.3.0.2.1 :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can download specific version of JDK 1.5 from the link you provided ([download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html)).

In short, as mentioned in Oracle's official Java documentation:

```
Both version numbers “1.5.0″ and “5.0″ are used to identify this release of the 
Java 2 Platform Standard Edition. Version “5.0″ is the product version, while 
“1.5.0″ is the developer version. The number “5.0″ is used to better reflect the 
level of maturity, stability, scalability and security of the J2SE.
```

Therefore the answer is yes, Java SE X and JDK 1.X are the same thing and usually used interchangeably.

[See here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/version-6-141920.html) for a more detailed explanation of the version numbering concept in Java.

You may also want to [see here](http://techtracer.com/2007/08/01/j2ee-or-jee-java-5-or-java-15-is-sun-crazy/) for quite similar discussion.

Answer (score 4):

You are right. Java 5 and Java 1.5 are interchangable. It's a branding thing - I think Sun decided that having something still on version 1 didn't sound great.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Java 1.5 and Java 5 are the same thing.

Comment: Yes. While downloading Java SE 5, the file name is `jdk-1_5_0_22-windows-i586-p.exe`